# Azure Function Local Debug Nothing Happening Portal Issue?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal

I am new to Azure and the Azure Portal and I think I have an issue on the portal side that I don't know how to resolve.
I created an Azure Timer Trigger function (Python) that worked fine on an Azure portal that I own.  However, when I try to do a local debug for a different Azure portal (owned by client), the local debug just "sits there".  It isn't failing.  It just isn't doing anything.

Here's the debug output:

```
For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2021-03-24T10:48:49.124Z] Worker process started and initialized.
[2021-03-24T10:48:51.320Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000A078673B'.
```

Then, it just doesn't do anything.

Any suggestions on  settings, etc I should be checking and correcting on the portal side?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: what do you mean by local debug?

Comment: When using vs code, running the azure function locally using the debug window.

Comment: Do you mean remote debug? Can you explain clearly?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what do you mean "do a local debug for a different Azure portal". So correct me if I got misunderstanding.

It seems your function is running successfully, cause we could see the information `Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000A078673B'`. You should check the schedule to make sure if it should be triggered in minutes or not.

Debug your Function project locally.

1. Create your function based on python from VS Code.
2. Configure the schedule in `function.json` file, and press F5 to debug, it would run like this:
   [image]